# Move a div after touch event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to produce a movement on a circle of some rectangular divs. I want that if a div is dragged near another div, the second div move within the first one the user is dragging. Is there a plugin that do this or I need to produce something calculating the position of 2 divs. And, the rectangular divs can be also 10 divs not only 2.

Here my solution.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#dynamic-container{width:400px; height:400px; background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; position:relative; border: 1px solid black;}
        div#innerCircle{width: 380px; height: 380px; position: absolute; left: 10px; top:10px; background-color: lightcoral;
                        border-radius:190px; -moz-border-radius: 190px; -webkit-border-radius: 190px;}           
        div.marker{width: 20px; height:20px; background: black; position:absolute; left:195px; cursor: pointer;
                    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
                    -moz-transform-origin:5px 200px;

                    transform:rotate(45deg);
                    transform-origin:5px 200px;                          

                    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
                    -ms-transform-origin:5px 200px;                                

                    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
                    -webkit-transform-origin:5px 200px;                       

                    z-index:17;
        } 
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery.overlaps.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        function rotateAnnotationCropper(offsetSelector, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, cropper){
            //alert(offsetSelector.left);

            var x = xCoordinate - offsetSelector.offset().left - offsetSelector.width()/2;
            var y = -1*(yCoordinate - offsetSelector.offset().top - offsetSelector.height()/2);
            var theta = Math.atan2(y,x)*(180/Math.PI);        


            var cssDegs = convertThetaToCssDegs(theta);
            var rotate = 'rotate(' +cssDegs + 'deg)';
            cropper.css({'-moz-transform': rotate, 'transform' : rotate, '-webkit-transform': rotate, '-ms-transform': rotate});
            $('body').on('mouseup', function(event){ $('body').unbind('mousemove')});

        }

        function convertThetaToCssDegs(theta){
            var cssDegs = 90 - theta;
            return cssDegs;
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){                


            //$('.marker-1').draggable();

            var items = $('#dynamic-container').find('.marker');
            var i = 0;
            var cssDegs = 15;
            var rotate = 'rotate(' +cssDegs + 'deg)';

            for (i; i<items.length; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    cssDegs = cssDegs*i;
                }else{
                    cssDegs = cssDegs+20;
                }

                console.log("cssDegs: "+cssDegs);
                rotate = 'rotate(' +cssDegs + 'deg)';
                //Imposto i gradi a tutti i punti per differenziarli al document ready
                $(items[i]).css({'-moz-transform': rotate, 'transform' : rotate, '-webkit-transform': rotate, '-ms-transform': rotate});
                //items[i].css("background-color","blue"); 
            }

            console.log(items);               

            $('.marker').on('mousedown', function(){
                $('body').on('mousemove', function(event){
                    //rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $('.marker'));
                    //rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $(event.target)); 
                    rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $(this).find('.marker-1')); 


                    var markers = $(this).find('.marker');
                    var over = overlap(markers[0],$('#container'));
                    if(markers[0] != over){
                        console.log($(markers[0]));
                        console.log(over);
                    }else{
                        console.log('not over');
                    }   

                });                                        
            });

            $('body').on('mouseup', function(event){ $('body').unbind('mousemove')});                     
        });

        function overlap (div1, div2){
            var res = $(div1).overlaps($(div2));
            return res;                
        }  

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id ="dynamic-container">
            <div class ="marker marker-1"></div>
            <div class ="marker marker-2"></div>
            <div id ="innerCircle"></div>
        </div>                
    </div>  
</body>
```

At the moment this snippet produce a circle with 2 divs. That can move on the circle border. I want that if the div the user drag a div when the dragged div touch the other, they move together.
I tried to use also jQuery Overlaps library to get if 2 divs are overlapped but I do something wrong.

Thanks in advance. Every library you can suggest are well accepted

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

A more complete example will be your example working:

Working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcbo9bs3/

```
        function rotateAnnotationCropper(offsetSelector, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, cropper){
            //alert(offsetSelector.left);

            var x = xCoordinate - offsetSelector.offset().left - offsetSelector.width()/2;
            var y = -1*(yCoordinate - offsetSelector.offset().top - offsetSelector.height()/2);
            var theta = Math.atan2(y,x)*(180/Math.PI);        


            var cssDegs = convertThetaToCssDegs(theta);
            var rotate = 'rotate(' +cssDegs + 'deg)';
            cropper.css({'-moz-transform': rotate, 'transform' : rotate, '-webkit-transform': rotate, '-ms-transform': rotate});
            $('body').on('mouseup', function(event){ $('body').unbind('mousemove')});

        }

        function convertThetaToCssDegs(theta){
            var cssDegs = 90 - theta;
            return cssDegs;
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){                


            //$('.marker-1').draggable();

            var items = $('#dynamic-container').find('.marker');
            var i = 0;
            var cssDegs = 15;
            var rotate = 'rotate(' +cssDegs + 'deg)';

            for (i; i<items.length; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    cssDegs = cssDegs*i;
                }else{
                    cssDegs = cssDegs+20;
                }

                console.log("cssDegs: "+cssDegs);
                rotate = 'rotate(' +cssDegs + 'deg)';
                //Imposto i gradi a tutti i punti per differenziarli al document ready
                $(items[i]).css({'-moz-transform': rotate, 'transform' : rotate, '-webkit-transform': rotate, '-ms-transform': rotate});
                //items[i].css("background-color","blue"); 
            }

            console.log(items);               

            $('.marker').on('mousedown', function(){
                $('body').on('mousemove', function(event){
                    //rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $('.marker'));
                    //rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $(event.target)); 
                    rotateAnnotationCropper($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $(this).find('.marker-1')); 
                    var markers = $(this).find('.marker');
                });                                        
            });

            $('body').on('mouseup', function(event){ $('body').unbind('mousemove')});                     
        }); 

window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision($('.marker-1'), $('.marker-2')));
}, 200);


function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $($div1).offset().left;
      var y1 = $($div1).offset().top;
      var h1 = $($div1).outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $($div1).outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $($div2).offset().left;
      var y2 = $($div2).offset().top;
      var h2 = $($div2).outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $($div2).outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
    }
```

To detect overlapping this code should work:

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $($div1).offset().left;
      var y1 = $($div1).offset().top;
      var h1 = $($div1).outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $($div1).outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $($div2).offset().left;
      var y2 = $($div2).offset().top;
      var h2 = $($div2).outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $($div2).outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
    }
```

You can apply that to your code (replacing the overlap function).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great! This worked for overlapping but now I have to move the other div. So now I have to find the second div position and move together.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, after you get a touch event, just align those two divs, if you coded the movement around the circle, moving those two divs together should take you 5 minutes. Let me know if you can't do that and I'll modify the example though.

Comment: I can move the other div without problems, but it is not smooth. Because I set x and y variables of the first + the width of the first div. And it's not ok because at the first touch it move for example for 30px on the circle.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing on an example? A fiddle will be great.

Comment: I did a fork of your adding what I am trying. I am tring to get new coordinates adding the height and width of the selected item. Now on jsfiddle isn't working as per mine. At this moment on jsfiddle You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/re2vs9fd/

Comment: No, sorry, I've made a small correction on my example but it isn't finished, I hope it helps but I can't completely fix it right now. https://jsfiddle.net/mcbo9bs3/1/ Take a look at the collision function, near the end.